# C++ how to avoid trailing zeroes?

Tags: c++, precision, digit

If you do

```
double number;
cout.precision(3)
cout<<number;
```

for a number like 1.23456 you get 1.234 but if the number is 1.2 you get 1.200. How to get both 1.234 and 1.2 (they are useless zeroes)? Suppose you don't know what number you have to print.

Comment: I don't think this is something you should "avoid". If we are talking about precision, then the zeros in 1.200 are not "useless". It sounds like you want a rounding function, NOT a precision function.

Comment: Perhaps I missed something, but [**this does *not* do what you're trying**](https://ideone.com/GgsVCh)? What version of C++ are you using (and toolchain info would be appreciated as well)?

Comment: Yes, I want exactly a rounding function but also truncation

Comment: No, C++ does exactly what I said in my examples

Comment: @user3290180 Maybe *your* C++ does. What do you think the link I provided was compiled with, Java? Again, *What standard of C++ are you using, and what toolchain*?

Comment: the default one in Ubuntu 12

Comment: So typing `$ g++ --version` shows what version?

Comment: It was my error, thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    cout << setprecision( 4 );
    cout << 1.23456 << endl;        // -> "1.235"
    cout << 1.2 << endl;            // -> "1.2"
}
```

It's that simple: it's what you get by default.

---

C++03 lacked a manipulator for resetting to default formatting after setting `fixed` or `scientific`. However, in C++11 the **`defaultfloat`** manipulator was introduced. You can use it like this:

```
#include <iostream>     // defaultfloat
#include <iomanip>      // setprecision
using namespace std;

#ifdef __GNUC__ // Also check for version number, e.g. 4.8.2 and earlier
    namespace std {
        inline
        auto defaultfloat( ios_base& stream )
            -> ios_base&
        { stream.unsetf( ios_base::floatfield ); return stream; }
    }
#endif

auto main() -> int
{
    cout << "Lots of digits: " << fixed << setprecision( 16 ) << 1.2 << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Deault presentation:" << endl;
    cout << defaultfloat;
    cout << 1.234 << endl;
    cout << 1.2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your example is missing the specific datum he's sending to stdout : 1.23456 should be clipped (though I think he doesn't realize it will result in 1.235, but thats beside the point), while 1.2 should simply "be".

Comment: Are you serious? I just made examples, then I said you don't know which number you are going to print because they are variables.
It the variables value is 1.23456 you can't do that because you don't get 1.234

Comment: I don't see how that's "what you get by default", when you've taken his example input of `1.23456` and changed it to `1.234` for the purposes of your answer.

Comment: @Praetorian: there are no trailing zeroes with the default float formatting. apparently you've been misled by the OP's (erroneous) claims.

Answer (score 1):

Did you even try your own example?
Trailing zeroés are NOT printed (by default).

In fact, one usually wants (!) those zeroes (they convey information and they avoid clobbering up the output).
This is achieved by cout << std::fixed.

Unless you have used std::fixed, 1.2 will produce 1.2, NOT 1.200, even with precision higher than 2.

BTW: Precision means all digits, not just those after the dot, hence precision=3 leads to 1.23 - UNLESS you go std::fixed, then only those after the dot are counted.

Answer (score 0):

You might write a manipulator to achieve your formatting:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct DecimalPrecision
{
    const T& value;
    const unsigned decimals;

    DecimalPrecision(const T& value, unsigned decimals)
    : value(value), decimals(decimals)
    {}

    void write(std::ostream& stream) const {
        std::ios_base::fmtflags flags = stream.flags();
        stream.unsetf(std::ios_base::floatfield);
        std::streamsize restore
            = stream.precision(std::ceil(std::log10(std::abs(value))) + decimals);
        stream << value;
        stream.precision(restore);
        stream.flags(flags);
    }
};

template <typename T>
inline DecimalPrecision<T> decimal_precision(const T& value, unsigned decimals) {
    return DecimalPrecision<T>(value, decimals);
}

template <typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const DecimalPrecision<T>& value) {
    value.write(stream);
    return stream;
}


#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
    double values[] = { 12345.6789, 1.23456789, 1.2 };
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0]); ++i)
        std::cout
            << i << ": "  << values[i] << '\n'
                 << "   " << decimal_precision(values[i], 2) << '\n';
}
```